# Autofac Resolve constructor instance from Container?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

How can I register a type which takes another type as part of it's constructed without passing an actual instance.  Say I have two ISurface types registered. I want to register a Car but i don't want to pass in a brand new instance. I want to use one of the surfaces already defined.

Per the documentation they state :

- Autofac sees that IDateWriter maps to TodayWriter so starts creating
  a TodayWriter.
- **Autofac sees that the TodayWriter needs an IOutput in    its
  constructor**.
- Autofac sees that IOutput maps to ConsoleOutput so    creates a new
  ConsoleOutput instance.

Then why must I pass in an instance of Highway when registering a Car?  Given that I have two Surfaces's registered how do I specify an existing surface?

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Highway>().Named<ISurface>("Highway");
builder.RegisterType<Ocean>().Named<ISurface>("Ocean");

builder.RegisterType<Car>().Named<IVehicle>("Car").WithParameter("surface", new Highway());
```

Why do I need to pass a **new Highway()**?

Here's my models.

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    void Move();
}

public interface ISurface
{
    string SurfaceType { get; }
}

public class Highway : ISurface
{
    public string SurfaceType => "Pavement";
}

public class Ocean : ISurface
{
    public string SurfaceType => "Ocean"
}

public class Car : IVehicle
{
    private ISurface _surface;

    public Car(ISurface surface)
    {
        _surface = surface;
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"I'm traveling at high speeds across {_surface.SurfaceType}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple things you can do here:

#### Option 1

This keeps in line with what you already have. You can still use `.WithParameter()` but instead pass in a `ResolvedParameter` instance to explain the parameter to find and how to fulfill the parameter:

```
builder.RegisterType<Car>().Named<IVehicle>( "Car" )
    .WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter(
            ( pInfo, ctx ) => pInfo.Name == "surface",
            ( pInfo, ctx ) => ctx.ResolveNamed<ISurface>( "Highway" )
            )
    );
```

The first delegate passed to the `ResolvedParameter` constructor provides a way to find the parameter to fulfill, and the second delegate uses the `IComponentContext` to resolve the `Highway` instance from the Autofac container.

Alternatively there is an overload to `WithParameter()` that you can use without having to explicitly create a `ResolvedParameter`:

```
builder.RegisterType<Car>().Named<IVehicle>( "Car" )
    .WithParameter(
    ( pInfo, ctx ) => pInfo.Name == "surface",
    ( pInfo, ctx ) => ctx.ResolveNamed<ISurface>( "Highway" ) );
```

#### Option 2

This option uses registration with a lambda expression:

```
builder.Register( ( ctx ) => new Car( ctx.ResolveNamed<ISurface>( "Highway" ) ) ).Named<IVehicle>( "Car" );
```

Here you can see that I'm passing a lambda that represents my factory function which will again use the `IComponentContext` to resolve the `Highway` from the Autofac container.

#### NOTE

I also read from your question that you wanted the same instance of `ISurface` each time you requested it.  If this is what you want, then you'll need to update your `ISurface` registrations to include `.SingleInstance()` :

```
builder.RegisterType<Highway>().Named<ISurface>( "Highway" ).SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<Ocean>().Named<ISurface>( "Ocean" ).SingleInstance();
```

The default lifetime given to registrations is `InstancePerDependency` which means that the Autofac resolver will give a new instance of the object every time it is requested. `SingleInstance` is essentially a singleton.  You'll only get one instance created and that instance will be returned on every request.  Here's a [link](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-dependency) to that info

Comment: Beautiful explanation.