# Multiple registration configuration based on string info Autofac

Tags: autofac

Finally I found the answer, thanks @yeah-buddy 
[Autofac Resolve constructor instance from Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985987/autofac-resolve-constructor-instance-from-container)

```
public class Car
{
    public Car(IEngine engine) { }
}

public interface IEngine { }

public interface IRepository { }

public class Engine : IEngine
{
    public Engine(IRepository repository) { }
}

public class GenericRepository : IRepository
{
    public GenericRepository(string carName) { } // !!! Generic Repository write information to carName table, this dependency is keypoint)
}
```

**I want to register:**

- "Ferrari": Use `Engine` with `GenericRepository("Ferrari")`
- "Volvo": Use `Engine` with `GenericRepository("Volvo")`

**I want to resolve:**

- Get "Ferrari" Car
- Get "Ferrari" Repository

How can I achieve this requirement by Autofac?

Comment: You should add examples showing how you plan on resolving these things. Also include the list of docs you've read and searches you've done so folks don't waste time giving you answers you've determined won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autofac Resolve constructor instance from Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985987/autofac-resolve-constructor-instance-from-container)

Comment: Hi @TravisIllig, I have been trying to find answer for 3 days, I'm not denigrating Autofac, I chose it and yes it is very well documented, but sometimes people can have different perspective to problems. I did not use the words of other question, only problem is that. Best wishes.